# CardBoard unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, google-cardboard

I am developing a 2D game for cardboard. I download the GoogleVr assents and I import in my project. Then I add GvrViewerMain at my Hierarchy in my scene. When I run the scene I have 2 cameras and I want center scene in both my cameras and remove the lens effect. I'm trying for days at change this settings but without success. 
Please help me it's very important.

UPDATE: This is my current situation
[image]

Comment: Why do you use the Cardboard SDK while Unity support natively the Cardboard.

Comment: Because I found only tutorials when use Cardboard Sdk. My purpose is a game app for cardboard. I want divide the screen for kids with Amblyopia and show in a screen normal image while in another screen riduce the image visibility

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by `center scene in both my cameras and remove the lens effect`

Comment: I Update with image. I have two cameras but the scene is not at centre of any camera. Furthermore the image is not flat.it's clearer now?

Comment: On the flatness: I was pretty sure the distortion was *required* for VR games, as in removing that effect will make it not work correctly on Cardboard. As for it being centered, it doesn't look centered because the cameras are offset from each other. You either need to make the....object wider so that it bleeds off the edges or move it closer to the camera.  It will never be perfect though because that discrepancy is what *makes it feel like there's depth* when viewed in a VR headset.